# Google OpenID Authentication

Tags: php, google-openid

I'm working on a new project which has Google authentication but its not working.

It's using this library: https://github.com/openid/php-openid

It's the error retrieved when I attempt to login:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function addExtension() on a non-object
```

I found its trying to make a requets to "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" but this page retrieves error 404.

Is this service still working?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's not since the Changes have not been updated on that in 8 years. Try here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2Migration?hl=en